# How do I move my site logo to the left, outside of it's container

Tags: css

I'm trying to move my site logo to the left, but when I use negative margin the logo disappears behind the column.

I photoshopped the desired outcome:

[image: Desired outcome]

This is the website URL: https://designthinkingworkshop.nl/

I've tried z-index in combination with negative margin-left and overflow visivle but I can't get the logo on top of the column next to it.

Comment: can you post some code? its easier to understand what are you doing

Comment: In your header tag, change the `<div class="container">` to `<div class="container-fluid">` and you'll get your logo closer to the left edge of the page (and subsequently have your menu closer to the right), to which you can futz with the individual margins to align it as you see fit

Comment: remove the 'over-flow:hidden' property on these css class selectors '.main-header .header-logo ' & '.main-header .header-logo ' . and then use 'margin or right: 100px;' property to move logo to left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without making any massive changes, this can be achieved by removing the 15px padding on your container:

```
.container {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

If it's important for the logo to be flush with the border, you could use a negative margin on it:

```
.header-logo.logo-image img {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

There are plenty of other ways to achieve the same, including redoing your header section.  I'm not a fan of your layout here, it could possibly be a lot cleaner.

Also, I'm sure sure whether you're using any animation or transition effects on your page, but viewing your page caused a large, continual increase in CPU usage by my browser process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I change the .container size, all the site content changes size. 

Is it possible to place only the logo in a bigger container whilst the rest of the content will stay like it was?